# Using views in Drupal

Tags: 7, views

I want to create a view page with the city events /attractions ... I want to categorize them as family , kids , outdoors etc. So that when a user clicks on a particular category they see the events/attractions listed under it.

How do I do this using Drupal 7 and views?

Comment: When you say "they see the events/attractions listed under it", you mean the events are presented inside the same view? Like an accordion like effect? Or a new page load with the list of events/attractions for the selected category? There are ways to do either of these.

Comment: Your question is very vague. You need to describe to us how your content is structured.

Comment: Hi Stefanos ....its a new a new page load with the list of events/attractions for the category. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way of doing this is with Contextual filters

-Create a view display Page (Block also works)

-Add **Contextual filter** Content has Taxonomy Term ID

-Leave **When the filter value is NOT in the URL** as Display all results

-On **When the filter value IS in the URL or a default is provided** check 'Specify validation criteria' and choose the vocabulary that has your events categories, leave filter type as 'Term ID'

Now when you hit the page url example.com/events it will list all the events from all categories

When you hit example.com/events/1 it will only list events from the category that it's term ID is 1 (say family is id 1 and outdoors is id 2, it will show all events categorized as family)

You could also make it filter by more than one term with other configurations options, and create URL aliases so your url becomes example.com/events/family

Answer (score 1):

In the **Filter Criteria** add a filter **Content: Has taxonomy term** .

Choose the Vocabulary with your category. In the next step check **Expose this filter to visitors, to allow them to change it** . Set the Label as you want and "Apply".

Anyway, try to be more specific in your question if you want a better answer.